# Compiled programs in 13.04 missing icons in launch bar (defaults to question mark)

Tags: unity, icons, compiling, .desktop

I use a custom compiled version of Wine and Minitube (no actual source changed, just compiled instead of installed from software centre), however for some reason their icons show up as grey question marks instead of the standard icon files. I'm pretty sure it's not an installation issue. I've attached my minitube installation log, if that's of any help:

```
gem@HAL9000:~/Downloads/minitube$ sudo make install
install -m 755 -p "build/target/minitube" "/usr/bin/minitube"
strip "/usr/bin/minitube"
cp -f -r /home/gem/Downloads/minitube/build/target/locale /usr/share/minitube/
install -m 644 -p /home/gem/Downloads/minitube/minitube.desktop /usr/share/applications/
install -m 644 -p /home/gem/Downloads/minitube/data/minitube.svg /usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/
install -m 644 -p /home/gem/Downloads/minitube/data/16x16/minitube.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/
install -m 644 -p /home/gem/Downloads/minitube/data/22x22/minitube.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/
install -m 644 -p /home/gem/Downloads/minitube/data/32x32/minitube.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/
install -m 644 -p /home/gem/Downloads/minitube/data/48x48/minitube.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/
install -m 644 -p /home/gem/Downloads/minitube/data/64x64/minitube.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/
install -m 644 -p /home/gem/Downloads/minitube/data/128x128/minitube.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/
install -m 644 -p /home/gem/Downloads/minitube/data/256x256/minitube.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/
install -m 644 -p /home/gem/Downloads/minitube/data/512x512/minitube.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/apps/
```

So, any idea what's going on and how can I fix it? Ubuntu 13.04, fresh install.

Comment: Add the contents of `/usr/share/minitube.desktop` to your question please.

Comment: Oops! I meant `/usr/share/applications/minitube.desktop`. Sorry.

Comment: @edwin Done, added!

Comment: Try setting the full icon path. Also make sure that `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/minitube.svg` does exist and that you've rebooted.

Comment: @edwin omg I love you!

Comment: If you found the solution, consider adding it as an answer (and accepting it as the solution). That way you can help others with the same issue. Glad I could be of help.

Comment: @edwin Yes, yes, I tried but it doesn't allow me until 8 hours have passed because I'm a new user :(

Comment: Oh, well. OK, but try to remember :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gem@HAL9000:/usr/share/applications$ sudo vim minitube.desktop
```

And setting the line:

```
Icon=minitube
```

To:

```
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/minitube.svg
```

Did the job perfectly!

Thanks @edwin !